# Ошибка при использовании оператора break, оператор подчеркивается красной линией и всплывает окно "Break outside switch or loop". Что это может быть?

Tags: java

```
 public void set(int index, int element) {
    if (index > size) {
        break;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
        arr[index] = element;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Потому что вы ничего не "прекращаете"

break указывает на то,что нужно прекратить выполнять цикл или switch,если хотите выйти из функции используйте return

```
public void set(int index, int element) {
    if (index > size) {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Та же самая ошибка, но уже в другом куске кода, return тоже не подходит, потому что метод с возвращаемым значением. Не подскажешь как решить?

Comment: Потому что функция void ничего не возвращает...

Comment: я знаю
public int get(int index) {
        if (index > size) {
            return;
        }
...остальная часть метода
       Тоже уже будет не правильно

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROomaUIke2c посмотрите это и/или еще какие-нибудь видео на ютуб,там все понятно и пошагово объясняется

Comment: Если мой ответ вам помог,то отметьте его.Спасибо